# Fileupload on protractor

Tags: protractor

I am involving in designing a image upload on protractor test in my local machine And  i am having difficulties to get the image on the popup window to be uploaded. here is my e2e test code,

```
this.uploadnewprofilepage = function () {
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(clickuploadonprofpage), 5000);
        clickuploadonprofpage.click();
        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(selectapicture), 5000);
        selectapicture.click();
        var path = require('path');
        var fileToUpload = '../Resourcefiles/filupimage.jpg',
        absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
        element(by.id("save-btn")).sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

however I could not get sendkeys to be worked to get the image on the image upload window.
my code snippets is  like this.Any comments on this is appreciated.thanks [image]

Comment: `.sendKeys()` will never work on a button. You need an input

Comment: yeap, and the `input` element is not necessary is around that button. I may be anywhere on page

Comment: @JoaquinCasco please be specific on the answer? i am kinda new to protractor

Comment: @LakmalRajith, what Joaquin meant wasthat .sendKeys() works only for input fields, you are trying to use it on a button, instead of .sendkeys, use .click()

Comment: @Alexandre thanks well noted, appreciate the help on this